# How to run battle.net when there is no blizzard games installed?

Tags: battle.net

When I installed Starcraft 2 on my PC the installer created a shortcut 'play starcraft 2' on my start menu. If I run it the Blizzard's Battle.net client application starts.

Later I uninstalled Starcraft 2 from my PC. The 'play starcraft 2' shortcut is gone from my start menu.

How can I run battle.net now that I don't have any blizzard games installed?

Comment: Have you tried searching for "battle.net" in the Start Menu?

Comment: @Nolonar I have, it's not there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its no longer called Battle.NET but **Blizzard App**

If installed in the default location it should be in

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Blizzard App

If you can't find it, its possible you have removed it. In that case you can download it from the [blizzard website](https://eu.battle.net/account/download/) It's the second last item.

Comment: I installed in a non-default location but found the `Battle.net` folder. I then added a shortcut to the `Battle.net Launcher.exe` in start menu. Problem solved. Thanks.